About the worship of Grihapati
In this chapter of Vana Parva, it states that Grihapati (avatar of Siva) as a worshippsble deity:-

"And that fire, under the name of Grihapati, is ever worshipped at all sacrifices and conveys all the oblations that are made in this world."

It's seems interesting, so my question is, Did any scripture mention about any methods to worship him?
